# Unable to export Chains class from Julia's Turing library

Tags: julia, turing-machines

I am using Julia's **Turing library** to do the analysis using the MCMC method, and I am able to get the output of type Chains and store it in the variable `chain`. However, I am unable to write it out to a `.jis` file. I get the following error.Please let me know how to solve it.

**code**

```
write(".jis", chain)
```

**error log**

```
MethodError: no method matching write(::IOStream, ::Chains{Float64, AxisArrays.AxisArray{Float64, 3, Array{Float64, 3}, Tuple{AxisArrays.Axis{:iter, StepRange{Int64, Int64}}, AxisArrays.Axis{:var, Vector{Symbol}}, AxisArrays.Axis{:chain, UnitRange{Int64}}}}, Missing, NamedTuple{(:parameters, :internals), Tuple{Vector{Symbol}, Vector{Symbol}}}, NamedTuple{(:start_time, :stop_time), Tuple{Float64, Float64}}})
Closest candidates are:
  write(::IO, ::Any) at io.jl:672
  write(::IO, ::Any, !Matched::Any...) at io.jl:673
  write(!Matched::FilePathsBase.AbstractPath, ::Any) at ~/.julia/packages/FilePathsBase/9kSEl/src/path.jl:771
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not entirely clear. But a possible answer is to use serialization/deserialization support of Julia. This can be done in the following way:

```
using Serialization
using Turing

# calculate chain here
#
# chain = ...
#

f = open("thefile.jls", "w")
serialize(f, chain)
close(f)
```

and then to read the `chain` in a new session:

```
using Serialization
using Turing

f = open("thefile.jls", "r")
chain = deserialize(f)
close(f)
```